# Displaying data getting fetched asynchronously in a RecyclerView in Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am trying to load the data list asynchronously and showing it on RecyclerView in fragments. However, the same implementation works for Activity class but fails for Fragment:

```
public class ItemThreeFragment extends Fragment {

String email;
private CompositeSubscription mSubscriptions;
HistoryAdapter historyAdapter;
RecyclerView recyclerView;


public static ItemThreeFragment newInstance() {
    ItemThreeFragment fragment = new ItemThreeFragment();
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    email = ((BaseApplication) getActivity().getApplication()).getEmail();
    mSubscriptions = new CompositeSubscription();
    getUserHistory(email);

}

private void getUserHistory(String email) {
    mSubscriptions.add(NetworkUtil.generic().getUserCheckinInfo(email)
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
            .subscribe(this::handleCheckInInfoResponse,this::handleError));

}

private void handleCheckInInfoResponse(List<Checkin> checkins) {
    System.out.println(checkins);
    historyAdapter = new HistoryAdapter(this.getActivity(), checkins);
    recyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

}

private void handleError(Throwable throwable) {
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_three, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.historyList);


    return rootView;
}
}
```

Any kind of suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try to set the adapter in onCreateView() instead of onCreate.
Check for data

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
recyclerView.setAdapter(historyAdapter);
```

Use these two lines onCreateView after you have fetched the data.

Comment: My list is getting updated in the handleCheckInInfoResponse() method and I have already added the lines over there. I have edited the program, please take a look again.